# How to Configure Xerces-C++ to process XIncludes prior to XML Schema Validation

Tags: c++, xml, xsd, xerces, xerces-c

Consider an XML file, **config.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Configuration
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation = "rules.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi                     = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xi                      = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
>
  <xi:include href="bunnies.xml" />
  <xi:include href="doggies.xml" />
</Configuration>
```

where **rules.xsd** is an XML Schema document describing the structure & constraints of **config.xml** after the XIncludes have been processed.

---

Using **xmllint** one is able to perform the XIncludes prior to XML Schema validation from the command line:

```
xmllint --xinclude --schema rules.xsd config.xml
```

Invalidate changes to the child **bunnies.xml** or **doggies.xml** will be picked up by the xmllint tool.

---

I am looking to use Xerces-C to apply XIncludes prior to XML Schema in order to determine if the software's configuration is valid prior to using the XML in runtime.  The road I am currently on has me looking at [Xerces's DOMLSParser](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/program-dom-3.html#DOMLSParserFeatures).

I have managed to get the parser to perform XML Schema validation - or XIncludes - but when I attempt to configure both behaviors, it appears the XML Schema validation checks are run prior to the XIncludes; which falsely invalidates the document.

---

Working from the [XInclude.cpp sample in Xerces-C](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/xerces/c/trunk/samples/src/XInclude/XInclude.cpp) the parser is initialized & configured like so:

```
static const XMLCh gLS[] = { chLatin_L, chLatin_S, chNull };
DOMImplementation *impl = DOMImplementationRegistry::getDOMImplementation(gLS);
DOMLSParser       *parser = ((DOMImplementationLS*)impl)->createLSParser(DOMImplementationLS::MODE_SYNCHRONOUS, 0);
DOMConfiguration  *config = parser->getDomConfig();

config->setParameter(XMLUni::fgDOMNamespaces, true);
config->setParameter(XMLUni::fgXercesSchema, true);
config->setParameter(XMLUni::fgXercesHandleMultipleImports, true);
config->setParameter(XMLUni::fgXercesSchemaFullChecking, true);
config->setParameter(XMLUni::fgXercesDoXInclude, true);

config->setParameter(XMLUni::fgDOMValidate, false);
```

If fgDOMValidate is enabled - validation fails as it runs prior to XIncludes.
If fgDOMValidate is disabled - validation does not run at all; but XIncludes do!

---

My question - is there a way to configure a Xerces-C parser to do the above?  Or should I be thinking of doing it more directly, say create a parser which will do XIncludes only - stream the output into memory - then create a parser which will handle XML Schemas and pass the included XML into another / or reconfigured parser?

Additionally, if anybody has experience or pointers on learning Xerces-C beyond their API documentation - that would be much appreciated!